# Detecting memory leaks using _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, crtdbg.h

This is my first time using the CRT library for detecting memory leaks, and I'm using Visual C++ 2003. As mentioned in this [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx), I included the statements in my program

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

followed by another header file that contains all other header files like stdio.h, windows.h and structure/function declarations. I also have

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

right before my function returns.

When I tried to build my program, I get the errors

```
error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
error C2059: syntax error: 'string'
error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_aligned_malloc_dbg' not allowed
```

for the function prototypes in malloc.h, e.g.

```
_CRTIMP void * __cdecl calloc(size_t, size_t);
_CRTIMP void * __cdecl free(void *);
```

etc.

How do I run the memory check debugger correctly?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne